# Why breakpoint aren't hit when webservice is called from Jquery (Ajax) and how to resolve?

Tags: c#, jquery, debugging, asmx

I'm writing a website using jQuery ajax calls to an asmx (existing) web service. When debugging breakpoints aren't hit when jQuery calls it. When invoking the web service using the test invoke breakpoints are hit.

How do I debug web services using jQuery while the service is running within the Cassini web server?

Comment: are you sure the ajax is hitting the Cassini instance ?
I would always set up IIS for this on a dedicated domain (edit hosts file) and then Attach to the running process.

Comment: after reading how to do it that way, I try to debug attached to the wpw3.exe. Now I'm getting the message the breakpoint will not hit because no symbols have been loaded for the document.

Comment: make sure you have "rebuilt all", check "tools/options/debugging" "Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)", seem to  remember it should be on.
Last resort run VS as administrator.